# PHP readfile() displays the file contents instead of forcing the browser to download the file

Tags: php, file, readfile

This is my first time trying to send a file to the user using php and I have the following setup:

```
if (file_exists($fullPath)) {

    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    //Use Content-Disposition: attachment to specify the filename
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fullPath));
    //No cache
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');

    //Define file size
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullPath));

    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($fullPath);
}else{
    echo "alert(\"File name is NOT FOUND: ".$fullPath."\");";
}
```

This does grab the file but it displays the file on the webpage as if I echo-ed the file contents. The script that holds this code is included with a require statement. If I manually call this single file by navigating to it through the browser, the file gets downloaded but If this script is included as a required statement within another script, then the file is not downloaded but just outputted to the screen.

My suspicion is that there may be some issue with the headers but I am not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: I have the same suspicion.  What does the containing PHP code do?  If the container is *nothing but* the require statement, does the problem persist?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` should reveal all.

Comment: Try something  like `header('Content-type: application/octet-stream')`

Comment: Check your log to see there's a "Headers already sent" warning.

Comment: Does your other script, that you include this in, output anything?

Comment: Is this included in a template, inside `<script>`-tags, since you're echoing `alert()` with out any tags at all?

Comment: I see you're calling `ob_clean()`. Does the calling script use `ob_start()`?

Comment: @David, if I create just a plain container script that requires the downloader code, then the file is being downloaded. I just checked the headers in both instances( my normal wrapper code and the plain wrapper ) and they are indeed different. That being said, the headers on my real code have content type of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". It seems the headers are already set and I can't really change them.

Comment: Would you please show the contents of the file that `require()`s this script? ... Or at least the lines up to and including the line where it is required?